# Is there something like GTK Headerbars in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, gtk, qml

I was recently reading the elementary OS journal, and I came across this article, [The Heuristics of Headerbars](http://elementaryos.org/journal/the-heuristics-of-headerbars). It talked about the new [GTK HeaderBar widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1HeaderBar.html), and all the benefits it has for design and user experience. I was wondering, is something like this possible for Qt/QML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qframe

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenubar

I wanted a system tray menu to be easier to navigate with lower accuracy clicks, and I ended up using this:

```
 m_tray_menu->setStyleSheet(
"QMenu {"
    "background-color: white;"
      "margin: 10px;"
 "}"

 "QMenu::item {"
      "padding: 2px 25px 2px 20px;"
     "margin: 10px;"
      "border: 1px solid transparent;"
     "font: 20px;"
     "height: 50px;"
     "width: 250px;"
 "}"

 "QMenu::item:selected {"
      "border-color: black;"
      "background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 150);"
 "}"
 );
```

The entire styling of all of QML uses similar css style syntax or qss as it is sometimes referred to in the docs.

Also if you want to depart from your desktop environment's window decorations, use the Qt Window Flags and the Qt Widget Attributes, and you can make anything your heart desires.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

For example:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget * parent): QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    // this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);// automatically set by previous attribute
}
```

Hope that helps.